# RecatJS: How to wait for REST Api response before loading the data in a table

Tags: reactjs, async-await, airtable

I'm trying to get data from an Airtable table using their API and displaying the data in a table. Like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GridComponent, Inject, ColumnsDirective, ColumnDirective, Search, Page } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids';

import { employeesData, employeesGrid } from '../data/dummy';
import { Header } from '../components';
import { getRotatedRectangleCoordinates } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts';

const Users = () => {


  var Airtable = require('airtable');
  var base = new Airtable({ apiKey: 'API-KEY' }).base('APP-ID');
  var listOfUsers = []

  base('Users').select({
    maxRecords: 200,
    view: "Grid view",
    fields: ["Nom complet", "Email"]
  }).firstPage(function (err, records) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    records.forEach(function (record) {
      listOfUsers.push(record.fields);
    });
  });

  console.log(listOfUsers)

  const toolbarOptions = ['Search'];

  const editing = { allowDeleting: true, allowEditing: true };

  return (
    <div className="m-2 md:m-10 mt-24 p-2 md:p-10 bg-white rounded-3xl">
      <Header category="Page" title="Users" />
      <GridComponent
        dataSource={listOfUsers}
        width="auto"
        allowPaging
        allowSorting
        pageSettings={{ pageCount: 5 }}
        editSettings={editing}
        toolbar={toolbarOptions}
      >
        <ColumnsDirective>
          {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */}
          {employeesGrid.map((item, index) => <ColumnDirective key={index} {...item} />)}
        </ColumnsDirective>
        <Inject services={[Search, Page]} />

      </GridComponent>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Users;
```

The data is parsed to `listOfUsers()`.

The problem is that, I think, the page and the table loads before the data gets retrieved, which displays an error on the page :

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are pushing items in `listOfUsers`. React needs new instance every time you change something so it can acknowledge this change. What you have to do is:

```
const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);
```

And later when you are updating `listOfUsers` with every `record`

```
setListIfUsers([...listOfRecords, record.fields]);
```

Comment: I see how this could work, but I can't manage to make it work... I only get the first record multiple times

Comment: You should check you logic if records are as you expected

Comment: The records are normal, I just noticed that it is actualy the last record that is only added